# NSDates created during API request showing odd results

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to use RestKit to import and map data to CoreData.

Here is the data from the API.

```
active": false,
"date": "2012-09-09",
"desc": "",
"end": "18:30",
"location": "",
"simStatus": "Accepted",
"start": "17:00",
"title": "The title"
```

When I try to map these to Core Data the times and sometimes the dates get altered. For instance, the above data stored in Core Data will end up with a start = 1970-1-1 23:00 and end = 1970-1-1 00:30?

*The times the API sends over are local times, the API knows when and where the app is used. Think sporting event, we know where/when the away game is.*

I need to get these times and dates stored in Core Data, the exact time hh:mm that the API hands them over. Not sure why Core Data or Restkit decides to change them? I understand the 1970 part as the start and end don't have dates, but why change the hour?

Does anyone know of a solution?

Below is the RestKit mapping code, which I have tried with timeZone, no timeZone, local timeZone, UTC timezone, etc...  I have also tried with and without en_US_POSIX.

```
NSDateFormatter* timeFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[timeFormatter  setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
timeFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
timeFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
gameMapping.dateFormatters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateFormatter, timeFormatter, nil ];

[gameMapping mapKeyPath:@"start"     toAttribute:@"start"];
[gameMapping mapKeyPath:@"end"       toAttribute:@"end"];
.......
```

Comment: Keep in mind that an NSDate object is assumed to be set to a time value relative to UTC/GMT, but, depending on what tool you use to look at it, the time value displayed may be "adjusted" to the current timezone.

Comment: In addition to what Hot Licks points out (that all NSDate objects are UTC), is the device guaranteed to be in the same time zone as the event is happening? (I know you say they're "local times", but local to the _event_ or to the _device_?) I'd strongly recommend you send start and end as full date+time values, with the time zone offset included. For example, "2012-09-09T18:30:00-05:00".

Comment: The full date and time is not an option as I don't control the API I am using.

Comment: That's a shame. Is there anything in that API that tells you what time zone these values are supposed to be in? Because you almost certainly want to set the time zone of the date formatter to _that_, and not the local time zone.

Comment: No, there is not. The guy who built is the CTO of company, WTF? I figured it out. I took the time they passed over and leave it alone. Then I create a new full-time date by combining the date attribute with the start attribute (same with the end + date attribute) but set the time as UTC. By setting it to UTC when I combine them iOS leaves them alone and doesn't try to add/subtract based on localTimezone (it leaves the new combined date alone). Then I store it as is. When I read the date I just accept/trust as local. @Sixten you are correct if you put your comment as the answer I check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hot Licks points out in his comment, all `NSDate` objects are UTC, so that's what you're seeing when you print those out. Because you're explicitly parsing the values in the device's time zone, you'll see a shift when you look at the resulting UTC values.

Normally, I'd *strongly* recommend sending things as full date & time values, with the time zone offset included. (For example, `"2012-09-09T18:30:00-05:00"`.) There are just too many variables involved not to be explicit about everything. Or at least passing the time zone as a separate (but still explicit) value.

If you don't have any control over the server side (as you say you don't), then your workaround of parsing the values *as though* they were UTC, and then hoping that things match up--while risky and brittle--sounds like it might be the best option you've got.

Comment: So change API to full date and time and fire CTO.